# Speeding up division by square roots, by approximation

Tags: go, math, floating-point

I have some integer that I want to divide by root 2:

```
var x int32
var sqrt_two = math.Sqrt(2)
for {
    result = float64(x) / sqrt_two
}
```

However, `result` can be an approximate solution, so we can remove the use of `math.Sqrt`.

99/70 approximately equals root 2, so we can write:

```
var x int32
for {
    result = float64(x * 70) / 99
    // fewer float64 operations than float(x) * 70 / 99
}
```

Is this efficient / worthwhile?

Comment: No. Per the [code](https://golang.org/src/math/sqrt.go?s=3702:3730#L82): `Sqrt is implemented in assembly on some systems.` "efficient/worthwhile" are also meaningless without context.

Comment: is the returned result float or integer?

Comment: You should calculate `Sqrt(0.5)` once and multiply by that (instead of dividing by sqrt(2)). If you want an integer result, find an approximation where the divisor is a power of two (this can be calculated very efficiently using shifting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first block, you're using `math.Sqrt(2)` just once. Thus, the cost which could be "considerable" is being amortized over all the iterations inside the `for` loop. The longer the loop, the less relevant it is such cost.

In the second block, you don't pre-compute the `70/99`, thus don't amortize and in principle, you'd end up doing more operations being the division comparatively more expensive than just a multiplication as in the first block.

It's very hard to say without more context if it's worthwhile. The best option would be to benchmark both situations and see if for your use case, i.e., your typical iteration length, which one is better.

Post Scriptum: I'm assuming you're ok with using the cruder approximation in your computation.